# Why does my kitten seem to be paralyzed?

Tags: cats, health

Golla, our 5 months old stray kitty was refusing food for about a week and has been having diarrhea. Yesterday evening he finally asked for food! we were really happy.

This morning he was in our bed and suddenly acted like he was going to vomit but pooped instead. Now he is not able to move, seemingly paralyzed.

He has a vet appointment in the evening, what can we do now to make him feel better in the meantime?

Answer (score 7):

Take the cat to the vet.

There is no other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to my cat once; in her case, she was stung by a scorpion. The vet initially said she had a stroke, but later we knew it was a scorpion sting. RLB is correct. You need to take the cat to the vet because she needs medicine for what her body is dealing with.